# Contesting a selected answer to an apparently abandoned question

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

Similar to this feature request: [Allow Accepted Answer recipient to give it away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/allow-accepted-answer-recipient-to-give-it-away)... and in the vain of several complaints like this one: [How do I request attention of an expert in a subject when an incorrect question gets upvoted and selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11895/how-do-i-request-attention-of-an-expert-in-a-subject-when-an-incorrect-question)... I would like to make a simplified request for a feature.

When, for whatever reason, an answer is accepted to a question and the owner of that answer changes his mind, but cannot delete it (because it was accepted), he should be able to indicate in some way that he disagrees with the acceptance (other than a comment that can get lost in a sea of other discussions). There should be no issues with reputation calculation or sorting, as these should not be affected - this would be for the benefit of the casual visitor of the site (one of the ones that still has to look at ads - you remember those?)

When an answer is accepted, the owner of that answer can disagree or contest that acceptance in the form causing of a visual change of the acceptance icon (something that calls attention to it slightly and lets a casual viewer know that there may be a better answer if they'd just scroll down a little further, perhaps an exclamation point beside the green check and title text that explains the contested status of the acceptance answer)

That's all - nothing more required of any users - if the OP changes the acceptance, that other answer provider has the same opportunity to contest; if the OP switches to another answer and then switches back to the original, the contested status remains.

This seems like a nearly trivial change (one or two days of work? plus a bit more for testing?), but would improve the site quite a bit I think.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Why would the poster of an answer ever want to *contest* that their answer was accepted? If it's wrong in some way, they can edit it.

Comment: Once again, acceptance is up to the OP. If he/she doesn't change it, there is nothing that can or should be done. Simple as that.

Comment: @Bart ...and this does nothing to modify that state of acceptance - it's a privileged (limited to answerer), focused (only one statement), and highlighted (can't get lost in other comments), and quick (not typing a comment, critically modifying your answer, or copying someone else's) way to indicate that you, the provider for the answer that has been accepted, wants to disagree with this acceptance

Comment: It does modify the state of acceptance. True, it does not undo the acceptance, but does interfere with the acceptance itself. Acceptance is up to the OP only and can be done so for whatever informed or uninformed reason. Visually changing it would be at odds with that very fundamental principle. Go any of the routes as suggested by Yannis, though even there I would personally object to deletion and rather go for the disassociation. But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

> When an answer is accepted, the owner of that answer can disagree or contest that acceptance in the form causing of a visual change of the acceptance icon (something that calls attention to it slightly and lets a casual viewer know that there may be a better answer if they'd just scroll down a little further, perhaps an exclamation point beside the green check and title text that explains the contested status of the acceptance answer)

If you want to disagree or contest the acceptance, just flag your answer for moderation attention and ask for it to be deleted. Your other option would be to ask for your account to be disassociated from the answer, again with a flag for moderation attention.

Comment: Just curious: would you as a moderator really act upon that? Or is this more a "only way possible, but success not guaranteed" type deal?

Comment: @Bart Well, I would. There are various opinions on whether we should delete accepted answers or not, however if the flag came from the answerer, it's a whole different story.

Comment: @Bart Related: [Why are accepted answers immune from Flagging link-only answers as Not an Answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135920/why-are-accepted-answers-immune-from-flagging-link-only-answers-as-not-an-answer)

Comment: Though that link speaks of answers we **as a community** have to some extent decided to be bad answers. If the accepted answer was downvoted more than upvoted, I would have less of a problem with deletion. If not, I would personally only agree with the disassociation.

Comment: @Bart I've seen on several occasions deleted accepted answers, so it's possible and it happens.

Comment: @Bart Yeah, I sneaked in disassociation in my answer (I always forget that's an option ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Oh sure, I've seen it as well. And I realize we're discussing a very unlikely scenario to begin with where it comes to the author of an accepted answer contesting its acceptance.